# Создание и использование элементов виджета в реальном времени

Tags: c++, qt

Кнопка при нажатии которой создаются файлы по количеству lineEdit , и заполняться данными лежащими в  lineEdit .

```
  void MainWindow::on_pB_oform_otch_clicked()
  {
   QFile file; // вначале можно не указывать файл
   QTextStream stream;
   int x=0;

   str_fam.append(QString("%1 %3").arg(trUtf8("file_fam")).arg(trUtf8(".txt")));
   file.setFileName(str_fam);
   file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   stream.setDevice(&file); // указываем, что работать будем с нашим файлом
   stream << ui->lE_fam->text();
   file.close(); // закрываем файл
   str_fam.clear();

   if(flanech_x>0)
   {
     int flanech_x_1 = flanech_x;
     int r=0;

     for ( r ; r<flanech_x_1 ; r++)
     {
         str_fam.append(QString("%1 %2 %3").arg(trUtf8("file_fam")).arg(r+1).arg(trUtf8(".txt")));
         file.setFileName(str_fam); // указываем файл
         file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); // открываем его для записи
         stream.setDevice(&file); // указываем, что работать будем с нашим файлом
         flanech_x = r;
         stream << cells[flanech_x]->text();
         file.close(); // закрываем файл
         str_fam.clear();
     }
   }
}
```

Этот код прекрасно работает с одним (последним LineEdit) но я как посмотрю с массивом не справляется .
 Как сделать так что бы этот код ложил данные из

```
  cells[flanech_x]
```

в фаил

```
  str_fam
```

//-------------------------------------------

использовал я код который дал мне alexis031182.
Результат примерно такой:

```
void MainWindow::writeText(const QString &fname, const QString &text)
{
    qDebug() << "qwerty";
    QFile file(fname);
    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly|QFile::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        qDebug() << "qwerty11";
        #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
            stream.setCodec("Windows-1251");
        #endif
        qDebug() << "qwerty22";
        stream << text << endl;
        qDebug() << "qwerty33";
        file.close();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pB_oform_otch_clicked() {
    qDebug() << "trylala";
    // Записываем строку из первого QLineEdit.
    writeText("file_fam.txt", ui->lE_fam->text());
    qDebug() << "trylala11";

    // Записываем строки из других QLineEdit в "cells".
    for(int i = 0; i < flanech_x; ++i) {
        qDebug() << "trylala22";
        const QString fname = QString("file_fam%1.txt").arg(i+1);
        qDebug() << "trylala33";
        writeText(fname, cells[i]->text());
    }
}
```

Первый фаил создается "file_fam.txt" и в него вкладывается строка (все ОК). НО потом ох хоть и проходит весь код все qDebug() срабатывают. Но почему то программа разваливается (-_-)\ , и файлы file_fam1 .txt (и так до 5 ) даже  не создаются. Так как в Qt дебагером я так не научился пользоваться (его встроенного нету)я даже не знаю что делать ;_;.

> В случае если переменная имеет значение больше, чем число элементов в массиве, то это приведёт к ошибке.
>   Именно это и было исправил , заработало .

Comment: В чем вопрос, что именно не работает?

Comment: Отформатируйте код в вопросе

Comment: отформатировал .

Comment: @timob256 , попробуйте рассуждать логически. Из первого `QLineEdit` текст успешно забирается и вставляется в файл. Значит механизм записи рабочий. Тогда цикл. Первое, на что нужно обратить внимание - это внешние по отношению к методу ресурсы, а именно переменная `flanech_x` и массив `cells`. В случае если переменная имеет значение больше, чем число элементов в массиве, то это приведёт к ошибке. Также ошибка возникнет, если в `cells` содержится указатель (-ли) на несуществующий `QLineEdit`. Проверяйте код, формирующий массив `cells` и присваивающий значение перменной `flanech_x`.

Comment: alexis031182 я по дебагам отлавливал , а тут они ВСЕ отрабатывают , а потом разваливается

Comment: alexis031182 Спасибо вы оказались правы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код, представленный в вопросе, лучше полностью заменить на что-нибудь иное, что будет немного попроще.

```
// Метод, выполняющий запись текстовой строки в файл.
void MainWindow::writeText(const QString &fname, const QString &text) {
    QFile file(fname);
    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly|QFile::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);

        #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
            stream.setCodec("Windows-1251");
        #endif

        stream << text << endl;

        file.close();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pB_oform_otch_clicked() {
    // Записываем строку из первого QLineEdit.
    writeText("file_fam.txt", ui->lE_fam->text());

    // Записываем строки из других QLineEdit в "cells".
    for(int i = 0; i < flanech_x; ++i) {
        const QString fname = QString("file_fam%1.txt").arg(i+1);
        writeText(fname, cells[i]->text());
    }
}
```

Постарайтесь не использовать массивы без необходимой на то причины. В Qt для хранения списка указателей обычно применяют `QList`. Корректность заполнения массива "cells" осталась за кадром, поэтому также проверьте и ту часть программы, где это заполнение производится.

Comment: У вы , воз снова не там .